# Generic MySQL Query for Trimming Column Data

Tags: mysql, string, trim

I have a Table in which one of the column contains data as follows:

```
file1 (1.1.1.1).txt
file2 (1.1.1.2).txt
file3 (1.1.1.3).txt
file4 (1.1.1.4).txt
```

I want to trim off the text from *Opening parenthesis*. After trimming, the Updated data should be as follows:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

Since the Records are in Hundreds, is there a *Generic* way to *Trim off* the unwanted text? How the Query is written in **MySQL**

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('hello world',' ',1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query could be like this:

```
         UPDATE your_table_here SET file_name = RTRIM(SUBSTRING(file_name, 1, LOCATE('(', file_name)) - 1 );
```

Just replace file_name and your_table

Comment: Output is coming as "file1 (". I want 'open parenthesis' and white space before it to be trimmed off.

Comment: What will be the Equivalent Query in ORACLE?

Comment: Just look for sub string / string position function in oracle. Watch how the indexes work and you ll be fine. I don't think it differs that much from the SQL standard

Answer (score 1):

Locate the parentheses, minus 2 positions should give you what you want.

MySQL

```
UPDATE your-table
    SET your-column = LEFT(your-column, LOCATE('(', your-column, 1)-2)
```

Same premise with Oracle syntax

```
UPDATE your-table
    SET your-column = SUBSTR(your-column, 1, INSTR(your-column, '(') - 2);
```

Comment: What will be the Equivalent Query in ORACLE?